# What's the meaning of this "Death" in "Mobile Attribution 101: The Death of App Attribution"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read that article [Mobile Attribution 101: The Death of App Attribution](https://blog.branch.io/mobile-attribution-101-the-death-of-app-attribution/). That article introduced some basic ideas about Mobile Attribution.

It confused me, why that article name as "The Death of App Attribution"? I just found none connection between Death and App Attribution.

So, could anyone please tell what's the meaning of this "Death" in "Mobile Attribution 101: The Death of App Attribution"?

Answer (score 1):

*Death* is often used metaphorically to refer to something ending.  It can be used for something that is not alive.

One of the topics in Chapter 2 of the article is

> why mobile attribution providers are losing relevance in our multi-platform world

So the relevance or usefulness of app attribution is coming to an end, or "dying".